# Visualization of results from object detection with TensorFlow not displaying

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-visualization, object-detection

I am trying to test the [SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector detection model pre-trained on the DOTA dataset](https://github.com/ringringyi/DOTA_models) in TensorFlow. I have followed Google's guide and everything works fine with errors.

However, after running the code belw I would expect to see a visualization of the results. But nothing happens.

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
      plt.imshow(image_np)
```

What can it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `plt.show()` at the end of your code, so the figure is being created but never displayed.